# Multidimensional array in twig php

Tags: php, arrays, json, twig, slim

I have a simple application which gets a response from clash of clans API in JSON formate. The response looks like this :

```
{"items":[{"tag":"#L22Y9C0P","name":"Team Dynamatrix","type":"inviteOnly","location":{"id":32000113,"name":"India","isCountry":true,"countryCode":"IN"},"badgeUrls":{"small":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/70\/jC8f86zyZeATqqGJ7M9dgLEcEBynlEYyCW19eHS6Yjs.png","large":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/512\/jC8f86zyZeATqqGJ7M9dgLEcEBynlEYyCW19eHS6Yjs.png","medium":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/200\/jC8f86zyZeATqqGJ7M9dgLEcEBynlEYyCW19eHS6Yjs.png"},"clanLevel":7,"clanPoints":14009,"requiredTrophies":0,"warFrequency":"always","warWinStreak":5,"warWins":87,"warTies":5,"warLosses":69,"isWarLogPublic":true,"members":26},{"tag":"#LYPL20Y0","name":"J. Dynamatrix","type":"inviteOnly","location":{"id":32000006,"name":"International","isCountry":false},"badgeUrls":{"small":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/70\/JSG91YdiTEH7CH2SLBOUjWaP_3at4j0alq711p-VhaQ.png","large":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/512\/JSG91YdiTEH7CH2SLBOUjWaP_3at4j0alq711p-VhaQ.png","medium":"https:\/\/api-assets.clashofclans.com\/badges\/200\/JSG91YdiTEH7CH2SLBOUjWaP_3at4j0alq711p-VhaQ.png"},"clanLevel":8,"clanPoints":12920,"requiredTrophies":1000,"warFrequency":"always","warWinStreak":3,"warWins":118,"isWarLogPublic":false,"members":25}],"paging":{"cursors":{}}}
```

Now, how can I access and display the name and other things of a clan in the view file using the `<ul></ul>` tag?

For more information on the API, checkout : https://developer.clashofclans.com/

Comment: what did you have tried ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @bc004346 I tried a lot and I was not successful. So, At last, I had only one option. That is to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the json first so that php will convert it into a array, using the json_decode(). Store it on a variable and then loop on to it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks for this anwer @pinoyCoder